# php spark serve error unable to write cache

Tags: codeigniter

Yesterday my app is fine, and today when i try to command

```
php spark serve
```

in git bash, i get this error :

```
CodeIgniter CLI Tool - Version 4.0.4 - Server-Time: 2021-09-15 13:52:28pm

An uncaught Exception was encountered

Type:        CodeIgniter\Cache\Exceptions\CacheException
Message:     Cache unable to write to C:\xampp\htdocs\prosold\writable\cache/
Filename:    C:\xampp\htdocs\prosold\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Cache\Exceptions\CacheException.php
Line Number: 55

        Backtrace:
                                                -78 - C:\xampp\htdocs\prosold\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Cache\Handlers\FileHandler.php::forUnableToWrite
                                                                -84 - C:\xampp\htdocs\prosold\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Cache\CacheFactory.php::__construct
                                                                -123 - C:\xampp\htdocs\prosold\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Config\Services.php::getHandler
                                                                -123 - C:\xampp\htdocs\prosold\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Config\BaseService.php::cache
                                                                -115 - C:\xampp\htdocs\prosold\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Config\Services.php::getSharedInstance
                                                                -102 - C:\xampp\htdocs\prosold\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\Common.php::cache
                                                                -629 - C:\xampp\htdocs\prosold\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\CodeIgniter.php::cache
                                                                -298 - C:\xampp\htdocs\prosold\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\CodeIgniter.php::displayCache
                                                                -86 - C:\xampp\htdocs\prosold\vendor\codeigniter4\framework\system\CLI\Console.php::run
                                                                -57 - C:\xampp\htdocs\prosold\spark::run
```

What should i do?